# How can I work around the error: "Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"?

Tags: java, image-processing, lambda, java-threads

I am trying to use multiple threads to filter pixels of images with my so called method filterImageParallel().

When I try to make a for loop and assign the coordinates of the image according to the integer value i in the for loop, i get an error saying: "Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"

Why does it happen and how can I work around it?

Here is the code:

'''

```
public static double[][] filterImageParallel(double[][] pixels, int width, int height, DoubleUnaryOperator filter, int numThreads) {
    
    ExecutorService tp = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    
    double[][] result = new double[width][height];
    int newWidth = width / numThreads;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        tp.submit(() -> {
            for (int x = i * newWidth; x < (i * newWidth) + newWidth; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                    result[x][y] = filter.applyAsDouble(pixels[x][y]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return result;
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

You need a `final` or effectively final copy of `i` inside the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
    int threadIndex = i;
    tp.submit(() -> {
        for (int x = threadIndex * newWidth; x < (threadIndex * newWidth) + newWidth; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                result[x][y] = filter.applyAsDouble(pixels[x][y]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Though note that your code will probably not work correctly if the width of the image is not evenly divisible by the number of threads.